# 301 Redirect multi level directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to redirect `www.example.com/dir/subdir/` to `www.example.com` but when I put the following in .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /dir/subdir/ https://www.example.com
```

then `www.example.com/dir/subdir/` redirects to `www.example.com/dir/`

Help appreciated.

Comment: The `Redirect` directive does prefix matching on the path, and appends any excess to the new URL. (What you say is happening still does not make sense though with that.) You need to use a `RewriteRule` for this.

Comment: Thx @CBroe, are you able to help me with the RewriteRule? I'm no regex expert.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^dir/subdir/$ https://www.example.com/ [R=301, L]` should do it, if you want to redirect requests for the directory only. If you want it for all URLs that _start_ with that path, remove the `$` that anchors the pattern at the end. (And use `R=302` for testing for, make it a permanent redirect with 301 only once you got it working as desired, otherwise your browser cache is likely to fool you during testing.)